# Show differences in two ranges of data from the same table in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, difference, tabular

I have been searching and testing and searching and testing, but cannot find an exact or even almost exact answer with tweaks.

I have a table with the following columns:

```
RRD EMP_ID  JOB_REQ POS_NUM CANDIDATE_ID    EMP_STATUS  WORKER_TYPE CONT_SUP_NAME   REMOTE_FLAG emp_NAME    FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   RECENT_HIRE_DATE    ORIG_HIRE_DATE  DEPT_NUM    DEPT_NAME   FUNCTIONAL_GROUP    PAY_TYPE    JOB_TITLE   JOB_CODE    JOB_FAMILY  JOB_GROUP   JOB_FUNCTION    WORK_PHONE  EMAIL   EMP_MGR_LVL ANNUAL_RATE HRLY_RATE   EMP_TYPE    TIME_TYPE   EXEMPT  EXPECTED_HOURS  COMP_GRADE  WORK_LOC_ID WORK_LOC_NAME   WORK_LOC_ADD_1  WORK_LOC_ADD_2  WORK_LOC_CITY   WORK_LOC_STATE  WORK_LOC_ZIP    HOME_ADD_1  HOME_ADD_2  HOME_ADD_CITY   HOME_ADD_STATE  HOME_ADD_ZIP    HOME_ADD_ST LOA REPORTS_TO  REPORTS_TO_EMP_ID   REPORTS_TO_EMAIL    REPORTS_TO_MGR_LVL  emp_rank    MGR_LVL_NUM HIERARCHY_TIER  TIER_1  TIER_2  TIER_3  TIER_4  TIER_5  TIER_6  Snapshot_FTE    Period_FTE  Info_Source Calendar_period
```

RRD is the Run date and there are usually around 276 rows for each run date of employee data. So each time the data is run we have nearly the same data, however there may be a columns that differ when the data is run again. To give a better idea the data can look similar to these few columns below:

table 1

[image]

I would need to see the difference of the above when comparing the rows of data by date (2018-06-04 vs 2018-06-01); so the only thing that had changed between the two data pulls (two dates) was the 'Period_FTE' column. I have tried EXCEPT but I can't specify which column(s) have changed. I've tried combinations of EXCEPT, INTERSECT, UNION, UNION ALL and have even tried case stmts.

table2

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2016